# how to assign values to DataKeyNames in gridview programatically using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView. I am adding columns in it through c# in GridView `gvExemptSub` and retrieving data from another GridView `gvSubj` on button click. I want to assign data row values to DataKeyNames which I am retrieving from another GridView but I don't know how.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvExemptSub" runat="server" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="LID,BID">
    <Columns>                     
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void BtnAddSubj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                               
    DataTable  dt = new DataTable();
    dt.TableName = "ExemptSubj";
    dt.Columns.Add("QUALIFICATION", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("SUBJECT", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("LEVEL", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("UNIVERSITY", typeof(string));                   

    DataRow dr;

    foreach (GridViewRow srow in gvSubj.Rows)
    {
        if (srow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {                           
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = ddlQualification.SelectedItem;
            string SUBJECT = srow.Cells[1].Text;
            SUBJECT = SUBJECT.Replace("amp;", "");
            dr[1] = SUBJECT;                               
            dr[4] = int.Parse(gvSubj.DataKeys[srow.RowIndex]["LEVEL_ID"].ToString());
            dr[2] = srow.Cells[2].Text;
            dr[3] = ddlUNI.SelectedItem.Text;
            dr[5] = ddlUNI.SelectedValue;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);                            
        }
    }
    ViewState["ExemptSubj"] = dt;
    //gvExemptSubj.DataKeyNames =  (dr[4], dr[5])
    gvExemptSubj.DataSource = dt;
    gvExemptSubj.DataBind(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind them programmatically with an string array:

```
GridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[2] { "ColumnA", "ColumnB" };
```

Comment: how can i assign ddlUNI.SelectedValue as Datarow to DatakeyNames "BID" Which is not a column...

Comment: You cannot. The key has to be present in the dataset. It could work if you add a datakey column: `dt.Columns.Add("DATAKEY", typeof(int)); `

Comment: then how can i hide that datakey column ? because i don't want to make BID, LID visible in the gridview ...

Comment: If you do not want a column visible when using autogenerated columns then you need to hide them in the onrowdatabound or onrowcreated events. Or stop using datakeys.